# Issue creating regex patterns for batch file syntax highlighting

Tags: c#, regex

I have the following code to create syntax highlighting for a text editor that I am working on. It uses the FastColoredTextBox component. I can't quite get the regex pattern for highlighting batch file variables correct.

```
private void batchSyntaxHighlight(FastColoredTextBox fctb)
    {
        fctb.LeftBracket = '(';
        fctb.RightBracket = ')';
        fctb.LeftBracket2 = '\x0';
        fctb.RightBracket2 = '\x0';
        Range e = fctb.Range;
        e.ClearStyle(StyleIndex.All);
        //clear style of changed range
        e.ClearStyle(BlueStyle, BoldStyle, GrayStyle, MagentaStyle, GreenStyleItalic, BrownStyleItalic, YellowStyle);
        //variable highlighting
        e.SetStyle(YellowStyle, "(\".+?\"|\'.+?\')", RegexOptions.Singleline);
        //comment highlighting
        e.SetStyle(GreenStyleItalic, @"(REM.*)");
        //attribute highlighting
        e.SetStyle(GrayStyle, @"^\s*(?<range>\[.+?\])\s*$", RegexOptions.Multiline);
        //class name highlighting
        e.SetStyle(BoldStyle, @"(:.*)");
        //symbol highlighting
        e.SetStyle(MagentaStyle, @"(@|%)", RegexOptions.Singleline);
        e.SetStyle(RedStyle, @"(\*)", RegexOptions.Singleline);
        //keyword highlighting
        e.SetStyle(BlueStyle, @"\b(set|SET|echo|Echo|ECHO|FOR|for|PUSHD|pushd|POPD|popd|pause|PAUSE|exit|Exit|EXIT|cd|CD|If|IF|if|ELSE|Else|else|GOTO|goto|DEL|del)");
        //clear folding markers
        e.ClearFoldingMarkers();
        BATCH_HIGHLIGHTING = true;
    }
```

Using this code I can't seem to highlight strings between two '%' symbols without highlighting almost the entire file because many lines will only contain one '%' symbol or two right next to each other.

I am also having trouble with '::' comments. In order to highlight the labels I have created the regex pattern to match any line that has a ':' in it followed by all characters that proceed it.

I want to get the highlighting correct so that labels will be highlighting BoldStyle and '::' comments will be highlighted GreenItalicStyle without any conflicts. I would also like to be able to highlight strings that lay between two '%' symbols without conflicts (such as a line that contains only one '%')

All this should only be highlighted if not in a comment.

**EDIT**: Currently the code only highlights '%' symbols by themselves as I was unable to get the code to work for highlighting between them without causing major syntax issues.

Comment: For the % issue, is that the MagentaStyle?  Also, just to clarify, you want the percentages to be highlighted if there is something between them and both percentages have to be on the same line?

Comment: @DougF Yes that is correct.

Comment: OK, if that's the case, I did a regex at https://regex101.com/r/tdgSAZ/1/ if you want to check it out to see if it works for you.  If it doesn't, let me know what's wrong and I'll give it another shot.

Comment: @DougF Tried it, it just highlighted almost the entire file because one of the lines at the top contains just one '%'.

Comment: That may be because you were using the PHP flavor in that regex tool.

Comment: It shouldn't matter unless the regex for FastColoredTextBox is different somehow (besides being in C#).  Let's try one small change.  Try %(.+?)% this time.  The only difference is that there is a question mark after the plus sign, which means that it's non-greedy.  In the meantime, I'll try it out in dotnetfiddle, which is an online C# compiler.

Comment: For your keyword highlight, why not use case-insensitivity? `(?i`...`)`.

Comment: Your comments don't seem to match up with batch file highlighting? If you want comments to override other styles, you should mark them last. Since labels and comments must start at the beginning of the line, I would suggest using `^` in your regex patterns: labels `@"^:[^:].+?(:| |$)"` comments `@"::.+$"`. Also, why do you have parens around a lot of your patterns? They do nothing...

Comment: Thank you @DougF I will give it a shot!

Comment: @NetMage I tried your patterns but they don't seem to work...

Comment: @DougF It looks like it almost works, it only breaks when there are no characters between the % symbols.

Comment: @ZachPedigo What do you mean by that?  Do you mean that it's still picking up %% or that it's not picking up %% or something else?

Comment: @DougF It acts as though There is no end to the pattern match, it will highlight everything after the first % if the second is directly behind with no other characters in between.

Comment: @ZachPedigo OK, I think I see where I went wrong.  This time I'm doing this dotnetfiddle at https://dotnetfiddle.net/AAHh0U and I think this will work for you.  I had to use RegexOptions.Multiline.  Give it a go.  Sorry for all the back and forth.

Comment: @DougF It worked like a charm, but what is the difference between Singleline and Multiline?

Comment: @ZachPedigo Yeah I was confused with this as well.  It appears that when you select Singleline, it will evaluate your entire string as a single line, which is why the regex was ignoring the line breaks.  When you select Multiline, it will evaluate each line in your string separately with your regex pattern.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190050/discussion-between-zach-pedigo-and-doug-f).

Answer (score 0):

Big thanks to @DougF for helping me find this solution. The answer is:

```
@"^:[a-zA-Z]+"
```